# django pipeline -- how to pass uglifyjs pure_funcs via command line?

Tags: django, django-pipeline, uglifyjs2

I am trying to remove a list of functions using `pure_funcs` in [uglifyjs 2.4.13](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/v2.4.13).

When my settings are as follows:

```
PIPELINE_UGLIFYJS_ARGUMENTS = "-c pure_funcs=['App.LOG.info']"
```

I get the following error:

```
return ([App.LOG.info])
         ^
ReferenceError: App is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to add some back slashes so the quote wasn't parsed out:

```
PIPELINE_UGLIFYJS_ARGUMENTS = "-c pure_funcs=[\\\'App.LOG.info\\\']"
```